# How to specify a dynamic input and output path for Spark - in a typesafe config file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, date, amazon-s3, typesafe-config

So, I'm using a typesafe config file `application.properties` with Spark to read arguments externally. My input and output paths are specified like this:

```
dev.input.base.dir = s3://inp_bucket/my_dir/2021/03/21/00/
dev.output.base.dir = s3://oup_bucket/my_dir/2021/03/21/00/
```

Now this code is supposed to run daily, and everyday, the previous date must be worked on. So basically, I want to replace `2021/03/21` in the path(s) with `current_date()-1`. How do I achieve this?

If it's not possible in typesafe config, can I do it after reading the string, in `Scala`?

Answer (score 0):

If your path is a String you can decompose it with a regex and then use Date to substract the amount of days you need

Quick example below:

```
val myPathAsString = "s3://input_bucket/my_dir/2021/03/21/00"

val pathPattern = """(\w*:\/\/\w*\/\w*)\/(\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})\/(\w*)""".r
val dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
val dtf = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat)


myPathAsString match {
  case pathPattern(prev, date, suffix) => {
  val newDate = java.time.LocalDate.parse(date, dtf).minusDays(1)
  s"$prev/${newDate.format(dtf)}/$suffix"
}
case _ => myPathAsString
}
```